# Rails and Kaminari -- How to remove page gap [...]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My paginate parameter is an object, and the pagination shows like:

```
1, 2, ... > >>
```

But I want it to show like:

`1, 2 > >>`

How to config Kaminari?

And my object in controller is:

```
@Page = Pages.page(params[:page]).order(:id)
```

Kaminari code in my slim file is:

```
= paginate @Pages, window: 1
```

Comment: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#customizing-the-pagination-helper

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I find the way! Just add code:

```
.gap {
  display: none;
}
```

in my pagination.scss file!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/blob/master/kaminari-core/app/views/kaminari/_gap.html.erb) `gap` displays the content of `views.pagination.truncate` translation. Thus, one of the solutions would be to specify the empty value in the `config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  views:
    pagination:
      truncate: ''
```

The flexibility of the solution allows to specify any other string, which you would like to display instead of `...`